# If statements for click events in jquery

Tags: jquery

How to make an if statements for the click event?

For example, I already click the button and it triggers the functions and if I click that button again, it will trigger the second function and if I click that button again, it will trigger the third function. After the third function, the button disables itself.

How to do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it with javascript also. Try this below code

```
    <html>
     <head>
      <script>
   var counter = 0;

    function myFunction() {
        counter++;
        if (counter == 1) one();
        if (counter == 2) two();
        if (counter == 3) three();
    }

    function one() {
        alert('first function');
    }

    function two() {
        alert('second function');
    }

    function three() {
        alert('third function');
    }
        </script > < /head>
    <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me... !!!</button > < /body>
    </html >
```

See This [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/fozuvohu/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Add class into jQuery element using `addClass()` during first click; during next click, check if class is present using `hasClass()` and take different action; at the end of second click, remove class using `removeClass()` api.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this. YOu can set a global variable as flag for it

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var first = true;
        $("#myButton").click(function () {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            }
            else {
                alert("you clicked for the second time");
            }

        });
    });


</script>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="myButton" value="clickhere" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a flag here:

```
var flag = false;

jQuery('.button').click(function() {
    flag = !flag;

    if(flag) {
        // First Function    
    } else {
        // Second Function  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This way (if `btn` represents the button):

```
function first() {

  // Your code here

  btn.off().click(second);
}

function second() {

  // Your code here

  btn.off().click(third);
}

function third() {

  // Your code here    
}

btn.click(first);
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through this also :-
    http://jsfiddle.net/XwnGA/7/

```
var firstClick = true;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#test").click(function(){
    if(firstClick)
    {
        alert("firstclick");
        firstClick=false;
     }
    else
    {
       alert("second click");
    }

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can place all your functions in an array and then access them based on a counter set in the global scope, that acts as the index.

Something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;
    var funArray = [];
    funArray[0] = function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(e.target).text("first function");
    };
    funArray[1] = function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(e.target).text("second function");
    };
    funArray[2] = function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       $(e.target).text("third function");
    };
    $("a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault(); 
        if (count < funArray.length )
            funArray[count++](e);
        /*you could leave it with this in case you dont want the
        link to take over its default behavior. 

        But if you want the link to take over its default behavior
        you can add the following else condition :

        else
            $(this).off('click'); 
        */
    });
});
```

This way you can have as many functions you want for your click event. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SMC3Y/6/)

Comment: Awesome! This is almost of what I'm looking for! But there is one problem, I tested your fiddle but why it goes back to the first function? Is there a way after it goes to the third function. The button disables itself for the fourth click?

Comment: @CJRamki, your code would throw error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'remove' of undefined", as there is no onclick attribute for my element

Comment: Thought you might want to go back to the first one, hence wrote it that way. Updated the answer with the correct code. Fiddle - jsfiddle.net/SMC3Y/6/

Answer (score 0):

Go through this link.
http://jsfiddle.net/5Ng8T/

Use data-* attribute on your button tag in the view.

```
<input id="butn" type="button" value="Test" data-click="1">
```

jquery code goes like this

```
$("#butn").click(function(){
var attrVal = $("#butn").attr("data-click");
switch(attrVal)
{ 

  case "1":
      first();
      $("#butn").attr("data-click","2")
      break;
  case "2":
      second();
      $("#butn").attr("data-click","3")
      break;
  case "3":
      third();
      break;
  default:
      alert("hello");
      break;
}
});

function first(){
alert("first");
}

function second(){
alert("second");
}

function third(){
alert("third");
}
```